# allowed 8388 but found some other ports still open

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

my code

```
sudo ufw allow 8388
```

but if I scanned the all ports found that ports

```
22 80 110 443
```

also opened

if I checked the status of ufw

```
sudo ufw status
```

it only displayed 8388 was opened

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8388                       ALLOW       Anywhere
8388 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

confused by this case

your comment welcome

Comment: How did you scan the ports?

Comment: I used some online tools such as http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/